# A problem occurred configuring project ':iris_method_channel'

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am making an app with Flutter.

I haven't imported `iris_method_channel` directly. but I think it's in some other package that I use.

And when I build ios, it has no problem. But when I build android, it says

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':iris_method_channel'.
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.startsWith(String)" because "versionOutput" is null

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 894ms
Exception: Gradle task assembleDevDebug failed with exit code 1
```

How can I solve this issue?